# Преобразование массива. С добавлением ключей

Tags: php, массивы

Доброй ночи. 
Есть массив:

```
Array(
[0] => Ауди|А8|300лс
[1] => БМВ|X6|350лс
[2] => Мерседес|S6|370лс
)
```

Как преобразовать этот массив к отображению:

```
Array (
 [0]=>Array(
 CarMark => Ауди
 CarType => A8
 CarPower => 300лс
 )
 [1]=>Array(
 CarMark => БМВ
 CarType => X6
 CarPower => 350лс
 )

Ну и так далее в периоде(Неизвестно сколько может быть данных в 1 массиве)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум можно так:

```
$array = array('Ауди|А8|300лс', 'БМВ|X6|350лс', 'Мерседес|S6|370лс');
$temp = array();
$result = array();

foreach($array as $values) {
    $temp[] = explode('|', $values);
}

foreach($temp as $item) {
    $result[] = array(
        'CarMark' => $item[0],
        'CarType' => $item[1],
        'CarPower' => $item[2]
    );
}

var_dump($result);
```

Одним циклом:

```
$array = array('Ауди|А8|300лс', 'БМВ|X6|350лс', 'Мерседес|S6|370лс');
$result = array();

foreach($array as $values) {
    $item = explode('|', $values);

    $result[] = array(
        'CarMark' => $item[0],
        'CarType' => $item[1],
        'CarPower' => $item[2]
    );
}

var_dump($result);
```